# How much Maximum Data we can store in a File in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

i searched a little for the size of file in salesforce . i found this link 
    http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm&language=en_US

its showing that file size can be upto 2 GB.i have to store IDs in a text file and want to make it scalable for for nearly about 1 Million record .file size will be equal to 15 MB .can any one please provide some good tutorial how to create such kind of files and using it in apex for retrieving and updating data

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be working with the file in Apex then you are going to run into the [governor limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) when it gets large.

In a typical Apex class the heap size is limited to 6 MB. You can take this to 12 MB by using Batch Apex or a future method.

I'd suggest either using a custom object to store the data (preferable) or splitting the data into multiple files. Then you could use a batch Apex job to incrementally work through them.